# Eclipse templates in strings (PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, eclipse, templates

Is there a way to get the templates to work in strings?

e.g.
I have a JS class called "xyz". I build a website with php and have a variable called $bla.

$bla is a string where JS code is located and I want a kind of autocompletion to work.

$bla = "<script> xyz. </script>";

When I type xyz. it should show the methods of the JS class.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can always create a JS document, type the code and then copy to your PHP file. You probably want to use the HEREDOC syntax

Comment: I don't know about Eclipse so I will not answer, but I can tell you that's one of the awesome feature of PHPStorm :-)